# Generating a new new tablespace because of error ora-00607

Tags: oracle

Windows XP,
Oracle 9i,
The new undo tablespace has been generated. It named UNDOTBS_01 (old named UNDOTBS02). But now the database could not be open.
It gives an error: ora-01092.

```
SQL\> show parameter undo

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE

------------------------------------------------------------------

undo_management                      string      AUTO
undo_retention                       integer     10800
undo_suppress_errors                 boolean     FALSE
undo_tablespace                      string      UNDOTBS_01
SQL\> select name from v$tablespace;

NAME
-

SYSTEM
UNDOTBS
TEMP
DRSYS
INDX
TOOLS
USERS
XDB
LEVEL2
UNDOTBS02

10 rows selected.
```

How to open the database?

Comment: It appears that the _parameter_ is set, but the actual tablespace does not exist.

Comment: You are right! Practically, it occured if after creation of the tablespace didn't finished all the steps in altering the system/database.

Answer (score 0):

To close the thread and for future use:

1. Did a restore of hard drive partition with database (with error ora-00607, ora-00600). Most probably database get in that state after not proper shutdown of the power supply.
2. open cmd
3. set oracle_sid = database;
4. sqlplus /nolog
5. conn sys/sys as sysdba
6. startup
7. database return the errors: 00607 and 00600
8. show parameter undo (to see what you have in database)
   Soemthing like:
   NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
   —————————                        ——— ———– ———   ———————
   undo_management                      string      AUTO
   undo_retention                       integer     900
   undo_tablespace                      string      UNDOTBS
9. alter system set undo_management='MANUAL' scope = spfile;
10. shutdown immediate; in order point 9 to become valid
11. starup; again here database will return ora-00607 and ora-00600.
12. create undo tablespace
    NEW_UNDOTBS datafile
    'path location'
    size 1000m
    autoextend on
    next 1000m;
    Example of path: 'D:/oracle/oradata/instance name/NEW_UNDOTBS.DBF'
13. alter system set
    undo_tablespace= 'NEW_UNDOTBS'
    scope=spfile;
14. alter system set
    undo_management = 'AUTO'
    scope=spfile;
15. shutdown immediate;
16. startup;
    That's it. In my case the above works and solve the oras 607 and 600.